# How do I add a java gradle submodule to my Android module?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle

Suppose I have an Android application project in IntelliJ Idea with Gradle. Call it `MyApplication`.
What I want to do is to add a plain java library module (not Android library project) as a submodule to `MyApplication`. Lets call this module a `testlib`.
And then when whole project is built, I want this module compiled to jar and included to /libs folder of MyApplication.

What I tried: I've created a submodule *testlib* and included it as a dependency to *MyApplication*, but I get a following warning:

> Warning:Gradle: module 'testlib' won't be compiled. Unfortunately you
>   can't have non-Gradle Java module and Android-Gradle module in one
>   project.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Definitely possible. I have a project that contains both java modules and android modules. It looks like your java module may not be configured as a gradle module, so that will be the first thing to fix.

You would then want to add a custom gradle task to first build the java module, then copy the compiled jar to the libs folder, and then build the android module. 

I don't have time right now to give you any code but hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Have You solved this problem? I have the same and I'm stuck :(

Comment: I get the same error. I have a java module with maven and an android gradle module.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA does not support Gradle and Non-Gradle modules in one single project. A [comment from JetBrains](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5506688;jsessionid=18D875B067F418DB62E13A07774AF548) in their forum states this clearly.

> The solution is to either convert the Maven modules into Gradle
>   modules or split the project in two. With the latter approach, if you
>   build the plain java library module with Maven before building the
>   Gradle project, you will still be able to use it as a dependency in
>   the Android application project.
>
> Beware of using different Java language source levels in multi-module
>   Gradle projects. IntelliJ IDEA does not handle them correctly due to a
>   bug in either IntelliJ IDEA or Gradle. (There is a pending discussion
>   whether this should be fixed in the IDE or Gradle.)

Answer (score 0):

If you've created your project in IntelliJ as an Android-gradle project, then when you go to the "Add new module" window you should see an "Gradle: Java library" option like this:

[image]